# A problem in heat conduction at a steady state

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, heat-conduction

**Question :**

> Three rods of identical cross-sectional area and made from the same metal form the sides of an isosceles triangle $\triangle ABC$, right angled at $B$. The points $A$ and $B$ are maintained at temperatures $T$ and $\sqrt{2T}$, respectively. In the steady state, the temperature of the point $C$ is $Tc$. Assuming that only heat conduction takes place, what is $Tc/T$?

**Answer :** $Tc = \frac{3T}{\sqrt{2} + 1} \approx 1.24T$

**My problem :**
[image: Figure] 
In the given figure I have approximated $\sqrt{2}$ as $1.41$, as heat flows from high temperature to low temperature, I have showed the direction of heat flow at steady state. But how can this system be in steady state when all the heat is flowing towards point A and no heat is flowing away from $A$? (As steady is defined as the condition when there is no heat accumulation at any point, radiation is not an option, as the question explicitly states to consider conduction only.)

Comment: If the temperatures at A and B are given as being fixed, there will be heat reservoirs connected there that can absorb or emit any heat without changing the temperature. You may view the problem like an electrical conduction problem, where T plays the role of a voltage, and heat current plays the role of the electrical current.

Comment: Shouldn't this heat reservior thing be given in the question? @flaudemus

Comment: This is essentially what they did when they specified the temperatures at A and B.  Point A is essentially a heat sink for heat flowing from B along the two parallel paths BA, and BCA.

Comment: How is A a heat sink, does it radiate heat(which is not allowed by the question) or it has infinite heat capacity(not given in question)? @ChesterMiller

Comment: It is dipped in a constant-temperature bath (or whatever).